# I need to toggle between images just like tab menu bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a billing application as a web application. I need a tab menu bar structure.For this I have 2 images for each tab. To make a tab active and inactive I use two different image.Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.gold1 { position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1; } 
.gold2 { position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1; }

.gray1 { position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1; }
.gray2 { position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1; }


</style>
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("gold1")) {
        image.src = "gray1.svg";
    } else {
        image.src = "gold1.svg";
    }
}
function changeImage1() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage1');
    if (image.src.match("gray2")) {
        image.src = "gold2.svg";
    } else {
        image.src = "gray2.svg";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<img src="gray2.svg" id="myImage1" onclick="changeImage1()" class="gray2"/>


<img src="gold1.svg" id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" class="gold1"/>




</body>

</html>
```

Here when I click image it toggles between each other. But I need to toggle image and make active and inactive.

**edit 01**

```
<script src="https://localhost/bg_out/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#infoToggler img").click(function() {

    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('class')+'.svg');
});
```

this is the jquery file that I have added.

```
<div id="infoToggler">
<img src="gray3.svg" id="myImage2" class="gray2"/>
<img src="gray2.svg" id="myImage1" class="gray2"/>
<img src="gold1.svg" id="myImage"  class="gold1"/>
</div>
```

This is html file.

Answer (score 0):

A different maybe easier way to handle it:

Fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/T7FWF/12/

You need to add jquery : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div id="tabs"> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#tab1"><img width='40' height='40' src="http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/images/7/7e/Gentoo-small.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4"><img width='40' height='40' src="http://www.acdivoca.org/site/Lookup/RSS-feed-small-PNG/$file/RSS-feed-small-PNG.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2"><img width='40' height='40' src="http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/images2/thumb/d/da/Dignitas.png/100px-Dignitas.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3"><img width='40' height='40' src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/1588/farm_fresh_web/32/arrow_refresh_small.png" /></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1"><p> Words go here innit </p></div>
  <div id="tab4"><p> Testa texta </p></div>
  <div id="tab2"><p> eeyyeeeeee </p></div>
  <div id="tab3"><p> Cheap as chips </p></div>
</div>


$('#tabs').tabs();

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active{
    background:gray;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{
    background:gray;
}
```

Comment: so you want for more image... wait for some time , i will update

Comment: Should i add some js file?

Comment: you need to add jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i have check  , here is issue: https://localhost/bg_out/jquery.min.js you have use HTTPS on localhost instead of HTTP

Comment: Even if i have this in my code I do not get any output. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83956/discussion-between-bhavin-solanki-and-anu).

Comment: Can i change image instead of changing background color